# Is there any way to remove keyframes but maintain the curves of other frames as though they're still affected by the deleted frames? - for looping

Tags: animation

[image]

[image]

As stated above in the question.

I'm basically looking for ways to maintain an animation "loop" within a set of key frames so that the loop is confined to the set amount of keyframes when using NLA.

This can obviously be done manually but with lots of moving parts it would quickly become an extremely arduous task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an option to remove unnecessary keyframes.  If you apply it to an F-curve, then every keyframe that remains affects the shape of the curve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm assuming you're talking about the clean frames option?

Not quite what I'm after unfortunately. I'm looking for a way to maintain the bezier curve of a frame when other frames (that influence the shape of the curve) are removed.

Comment: I wasn't clear.  I'm trying to say that if a keyframe remains after you've cleaned frames then it is necessary.  Removing it will change the shape of the curve.  What you're looking for can't be done.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for the clarification. Thats a shame.

Comment: Okay I've actually figured out how to do it. Basically if you had a loop from 0 - 20, you'd create keyframes at the start and end point of the loop, change the curve handles on those to free, then delete keyframes that fall outside of your loop. This would allow you to have a clean (loop duration) NLA frame.